# How many I/O completion ports can be associated with a file?

Tags: winapi

I'm aware of that more IOCP with one file isn't useful. But is there really a hard limit of one IOCP per file documented ? I can't find anything in the documentation that says there's a limit.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for *practical* programming problems.

Comment: only 1 iocp can be associated with file

Comment: Maybe, but I didn't find that documented. Do you have a link ?

Comment: @BonitaMontero - direct not have, but not all is documented. implicitly this can be understood by reading about [*FileReplaceCompletionInformation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile). of course need not only read documentation but have something more.

Answer (score 0):

internally file is represent by [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class). here exist field *CompletionContext* which is can be 0 (initially) or point to `IO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT`. this structure is defined in *wdm.h*

```
typedef struct _IO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT {
    PVOID Port;
    PVOID Key;
} IO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT, *PIO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT;
```

here *Port* is referenced pointer to *IOCP* (internally this is *KQUEUE* object, declared in *ntifs.h*). so from there already visible that no more than 1 *IOCP* can be associated with file. so associate existing *IOCP* with file need use [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with [*`FileCompletionInformation`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class) or `CreateIoCompletionPort` function (very strange designed api). if you call [*`FileCompletionInformation`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class) on file after port already set - you got error (`STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

starting with *Windows 8.1* new File Information Class added - [*`FileReplaceCompletionInformation`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class):

> Change or remove the I/O completion port for the specified file
> handle. The caller supplies a pointer to a
> [FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_completion_information) structure that specifies a port
> handle and a completion key. If the port handle is non-NULL, this
> handle specifies a new I/O completion port to associate with the file
> handle. To remove the I/O completion port associated with the file
> handle, set the port handle in the structure to NULL. To get a port
> handle, a user-mode caller can call the *CreateIoCompletionPort*
> function.

from this also indirect clear that only single Port can be on file - if multiple - *Change or remove the I/O completion port* which port ?!

note that both *FileCompletionInformation* and *FileReplaceCompletionInformation* use [`FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_completion_information) structure as input.

```
typedef struct _FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION {
  HANDLE Port;
  PVOID  Key;
} FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION, *PFILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION;
```

easy view that it corresponded `IO_COMPLETION_CONTEXT` only `HANDLE` to IOCP used instead direct pointer.

note that *FileReplaceCompletionInformation* not at any time can replace existing IOCP on file, but only if no active I/O requests on file at time when this api called (*IRP list associated with the file object* must be empty), otherwise `STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL` will be returned.